# what symbol does return in a flowchart include?

Tags: python, flowchart

I have a python source code which has an if else and return condition.

if (arr[ind] < minimum):
return arr [ind];
else:
return minimum;

return in the flowchart is the symbol for assign or output?

I think return is included in the symbol output, but I'm not sure